# Are these two SQL statements equivalent?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-server-ce, inner-join

They return the same count of rows, but I'm not sure if one is an accident waiting to happen, or one is simply "the preferred method":

```
SELECT duckbill.id, duckbill.pack_size, duckbill.description, duckbill.platypus_id, duckbill.department, duckbill.subdepartment, duckbill.unit_cost, duckbill.unit_list, duckbill.open_qty, duckbill.UPC_code, duckbill.UPC_pack_size, duckbill.crv_id, duckbill_platypuss.platypus_item 
FROM duckbill 
INNER JOIN duckbill_platypuss ON duckbill.platypus_id = duckbill_platypuss.platypus_id

SELECT duckbill.id, duckbill.pack_size, duckbill.description, duckbill.platypus_id, duckbill.department, duckbill.subdepartment, duckbill.unit_cost, duckbill.unit_list, duckbill.open_qty, duckbill.UPC_code, duckbill.UPC_pack_size, duckbill.crv_id, duckbill_platypuss.platypus_item
FROM duckbill, duckbill_platypuss
WHERE (duckbill.platypus_id = duckbill_platypuss.platypus_id)
```

Comment: They should be equivalent, but I'd recommend using ANSI syntax (`INNER JOIN`) for readability.

Comment: mysql parser optimizes queries; so it will be same from practical view  point.

Comment: I'm not using MySQL, I'm using grandfather's SQL

Comment: There is a very [similar question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742196/is-cross-join-a-synonym-for-inner-join-without-on-clause) about this that explains it pretty well.

Comment: @MarkWilkins This looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax). Microsoft [recommends using explicit the `INNER JOIN` version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172122.aspx)

Comment: Are those real table names? :)

Comment: Yes, this app is for Exotic Mammals United (emu). See UHF for more info.

Comment: @NullUserException: Make your comment an answer, and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

So the reason there's a difference is due to the order of execution. You may not notice the difference on some table combinations, but on very large tables, you generally want to filter with the JOIN first.

This post gives some good information toward that end it looks like: [Order Of Execution of the SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596467/order-of-execution-of-the-query)

Comment: -1 I find it highly unlikely that the query optimizer would generate a different plan for these statements.

Comment: @NullUserException That's fair, given the specific query. I suppose I was thinking of it more generally. Although, really, the point you make in your comment above is the more appropriate one; that comma joins are generally a bad habit to get into regardless.