# Is CROSS JOIN the same as INNER JOIN / JOIN with out the ON condition?

Tags: mysql, join, conditional-statements, inner-join, cross-join

Why would you use the CROSS JOIN keyword if you can just do INNER JOIN and have no condition? Am I missing something? Also can cross joins have  on conditions?

Comment: Have you researched this online before posting the question?  I am sure there are tons of explanation.  So to answer your question, they're definitely not the same.

Comment: @Eric *they're definitely not the same* That's true... but not for MySQL.

Comment: In MySQL, the CROSS keyword is ignored, but it still might be included, either for portability or for clarity (human comprehension)

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: "Why" is not a clear question. It's never clear what a valid answer is. "Why" have CROSS JOIN in standard SQL when it means INNER JOIN ON 1=1? Because a bunch of things were balanced & a decision was made. Ask "what". After you research. Ask 1 clear specific non-duplicate question per post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is CROSS JOIN a synonym for INNER JOIN without ON clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742196/is-cross-join-a-synonym-for-inner-join-without-on-clause)

Answer (score 1):

> In MySQL, `JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`, and `INNER JOIN` are syntactic equivalents (they can replace each other).
>
> In standard SQL, they are not equivalent. `INNER JOIN` is used with an `ON` clause, `CROSS JOIN` is used otherwise.

[MySQL Reference Manual  /  ...  /  JOIN Clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)